# Chi - squared not clear how to understand the results

Tags: chi-squared-test

I'm having some trouble understanding the result of the chi squared test I did. The test results are:
chi: 6.87, p- value: 0.55, with 8 degrees of freedom.
I'm not sure now what my conclusion could be: since the chi I have is greater than 3,49 and smaller than 7,34, do I have to accept the H0 hypothesis with 90% of confidence?
This is the table I'm referring to:
 [image: This is the table I'm referring to:]

Comment: You don't need a table here; your software has given you a P-value. Your hypothesis is rejected at that level. If you chose in advance a threshold significance level of 10%, then it is certainly rejected at that level. (It's best not to describe a 10% significance level (e.g.) as a 90% confidence level (e.g.), if only because there is no confidence interval here around a parameter estimate.

Comment: It's hard to explain much about the result 9beyond whether you reject or not) without some context -- you don't even say what you're testing (which of many possible chi-squared tests you're doing). Are you testing independence? Goodness of fit? something else?

Comment: I would say that you have no  evidence that the null hypothesis is false. This is not a basis for concluding that the null hypothesis is true.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding slightly on what Nick Cox wrote - you are looking at the table the other way round - Often, we view a value of $p<0.05$ as significant. $\chi^2$ is a significance test. If the significance ($p$-value) is $0.55$ that means that the pattern of observed vs. expected values is not very strong. If you would want to reject the $H_0$ based on this, you would have a $55\%$ of being wrong. We do not accept $H_0$ in this case, we just can't reject it.